# Error: Compile Error: bootstrap-datepicker is not a helper

Tags: testing, ember.js

I am using

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-bootstrap-datepicker and Ember 2.18

package.json in devDependencies:

```
"ember-cli-bootstrap-datepicker": "0.6.1",
```

in hbs:

```
{{bootstrap-datepicker format="dd.mm.yy"}}
```

error after ember test:

```
actual: >
        null
    stack: >
        Error: Compile Error: bootstrap-datepicker is not a helper
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:21757:19
            at Compilers.compile (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:21369:13)
            at expr (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:21720:25)
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:21458:17
            at Compilers.compile (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:21369:13)
            at compileStatement (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:22127:20)
            at compileStatements (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:22132:13)
            at CompilableTemplate.compileStatic (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:22157:31)
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:18256:30
            at AppendOpcodes.evaluate (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:17481:13)
    message: >
        Died on test #1     at Module.callback (http://localhost:7357/assets/tests.js:1333:24)
            at Module.exports (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:119:32)
            at requireModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:34:18)
            at TestLoader.<anonymous> (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:10892:11)
            at TestLoader.require (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:10882:27)
            at TestLoader.loadModules (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:10874:16)
            at loadTests (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:12321:22): Compile Error: bootstrap-datepicker is not a helper
    negative: >
        false
    browser log: |
...
```

funny fact, if i remove format="dd.mm.yy" from {{}}, then it won't throw error. What am i supposed to add or what am i missing to test to work ? package's doc doesn't say anything

edit: i have seen this, [ember Error: Compile Error: is not a helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283645/ember-error-compile-error-is-not-a-helper), it seems i have everything right

Comment: What if you use `<BootstrapDatepicker>`? What version of Ember are you on?

Comment: I had the same issue and didn't manage to solve that problem. I had to import that library from npm and create custom component

Comment: @BuckDoyle <BootstrapDatepicker> throws an error "Uncaught Error: Compile Error: BootstrapDatepicker is not a helper" in browser ( unable to load the page ). I am on ember 2.18

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the dependencies and restarting `ember serve`?

Comment: @locks yes, i did